# School Outing Combinatorial Design Problem

Tags: reference-request, matching-theory, combinatorial-designs

So this is an actual organization problem I am dealing with right now as a high school teacher. There is a school outing, with $8$ groups of students. At the venue there are $7$ stations, where $2$ groups can compete against each other. Is there a way to organize the groupings over $7$ time intervals so that each group goes to each station exactly once, and each group plays each other group exactly once? Obviously over each interval there will be exactly $3$ stations that are unused.

One can generalize this problem to $2n$ groups, $2n-1$ stations, and $2n-1$ time intervals where $2$ groups play against each other, such that no group plays the same station twice, no group plays the same group twice, and no group gets left out in an interval. The original problem is the $n=4$ version of this.

The $n=1$ case is trivial (there are only two groups, and they play against each other once on the one station). The $n=2$ case can be fairly quickly seen to be impossible, as after the first interval, at least one of the stations must be used a second time, and there is no way to have a different pairing at that station that also doesn't have the same two groups compete.

Has this problem been worked on before? Is there any literature on it?

Edit: I have worked out a solution to the $n=4$ case:

```
Group: A    B    C    D    E    F    G

1:     12   34   56   78   XX   XX   XX

2:     57   68   XX   XX   13   24   XX

3:     XX   XX   14   23   58   67   XX

4:     36   XX   28   XX   47   XX   15

5:     XX   17   XX   45   26   XX   38

6:     XX   25   37   XX   XX   18   46

7:     48   XX   XX   16   XX   35   27
```

I'm still keen for a more general solution.

Edit 2: I am fairly certain the n=3 case is also impossible. There are enough values which can be filled in without loss of generality, after which sudokuing your way around the grid yields a contradiction. At this point I'm fairly sure that $n=4$ is the cutoff, after which there is a solution for all higher n, but that would be good to verify.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  In terms of duplicate bridge you want a $4$-table Howell movement.  Each set of boards is a station.  The pairs playing against each other are the two groups competing at that station (set of boards).  https://bridge.fandom.com/wiki/Howell_movement#4_tables

Comment: From the link: "**There is only one stationary pair**, with all other pairs move around in all rounds." This violates the requirement "no group plays the same station twice".

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem to be quite a correct solution as one group is stationary.

Comment: Not correct.  The stations are the boards, not the tables.  No one plays any set of boards twice.  @VTand

Comment: @ThomasBlok See comment above.

Comment: @RobertShore Right, my bad. I don’t play bridge, so I am unfamiliar the terms like tables and boards.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of graph theory, you have a complete graph $K_{2n}$ on $2n$ nodes (one node per group) and want to decompose it into $2n-1$ perfect matchings (one matching per time interval).  See [Perfect 1-factorization of $K_{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455298/perfect-1-factorization-of-k-2n)

But you also want its "transpose" to form such a decomposition.  For $n=4$, here is a solution obtained via integer linear programming, as in [Real World Problem - Groups Visiting Various Stations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401847/real-world-problem-groups-visiting-various-stations)

```
       A       B       C       D       E       F       G
1      {}      {5,7}   {3,4}   {}      {2,6}   {}      {1,8}
2      {}      {}      {1,7}   {2,3}   {4,8}   {5,6}   {}
3      {2,4}   {3,8}   {}      {6,7}   {1,5}   {}      {}
4      {1,6}   {}      {}      {}      {3,7}   {2,8}   {4,5}
5      {}      {1,2}   {}      {5,8}   {}      {4,7}   {3,6}
6      {3,5}   {}      {6,8}   {1,4}   {}      {}      {2,7}
7      {7,8}   {4,6}   {2,5}   {}      {}      {1,3}   {}
```

And here's a solution for $n=5$:

```
       A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I
1      {}      {}      {5,8}   {}      {}      {6,7}   {1,4}   {3,9}   {2,10}
2      {1,2}   {}      {3,10}  {}      {5,7}   {}      {}      {4,6}   {8,9}
3      {}      {4,5}   {}      {1,8}   {6,10}  {2,9}   {3,7}   {}      {}
4      {5,9}   {2,6}   {}      {}      {}      {3,8}   {}      {1,10}  {4,7}
5      {}      {}      {2,4}   {3,6}   {}      {1,5}   {9,10}  {7,8}   {}
6      {3,4}   {7,9}   {}      {5,10}  {}      {}      {2,8}   {}      {1,6}
7      {}      {8,10}  {1,7}   {4,9}   {2,3}   {}      {5,6}   {}      {}
8      {6,8}   {}      {}      {2,7}   {1,9}   {4,10}  {}      {}      {3,5}
9      {7,10}  {1,3}   {6,9}   {}      {4,8}   {}      {}      {2,5}   {}
```

Comment: Not quite. The perfect matching must be done in such a way that no student is at the same station twice. In other words, each edge of the $2n-1$ perfect matchings must be numbered (with a number from 1 to $2n-1$) such that no two edges with the same number share a vertex.

Comment: For decompositions with that additional constraint, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401847/real-world-problem-groups-visiting-various-stations

Comment: That seems similar, but not quite what I am asking. See my edited OP for an example when n=4.

Comment: I used that approach to find a solution for $n=1$ and $n=4$ (see my updated answer).  I also confirmed that $n=2$ and $n=3$ are infeasible.

Comment: Nice, that looks good! Are you able to check the $n=5$ case to see if that is possible?

Comment: It’s possible.  That’s a $5$-table Howell movement.